# Background-image shorthand not working but long written version does. How do I figure this out?

Tags: html, css

Currently trying to figure out why my Shorthand command is not working.

````
```
#home::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
background-image: url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat center / cover;

/* background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover; */

height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
opacity: .9;
}
 ```
````

If I use the shorthand property as written, the img disappears. But if I use long version as written in slash comment, it works flawlessly. What am I doing wrong here?

Don't mind the noob question, started learning web development 3 days ago :)

Comment: try to share proper code you misse dthe shorthand property in above code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-image` property can only set the background image.
If you want to combine multiple background settings, the shorthand is the `background` property

Comment: So that was the mistake. Thank you!